# Why can't input anything in a pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game.
The function "board_print" displays the game board, but for some reason I am not able to click on the "quit" button at the top right or click anywhere on the board... why?

```
pygame.init()
LEFT = 1
SCROLL = 2
RIGHT = 3
backgrouמd = [255, 174, 201]
black = (0,0,0)
line_color = (0, 0, 255)
w = 800
h = 800
X_img = r'C:\Users\aviro\Desktop\coollogo_com-20139270.png'
O_img = r'C:\Users\aviro\Desktop\coollogo_com-1453599.png'
o_pose_list = []
x_pose_list = []
finish = False
size = (w, h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
game_end_count = 0
slash = 0
backslash = 0
row0 = 0
row1 = 0
row2 = 0
line0 = 0
line1 = 0
line2 = 0
board = ([[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']])
ans_list = []
x_key = ('0', '1', '2')
user_ans = ""
o_image = pygame.image.load(O_img).convert_alpha()
x_image = pygame.image.load(X_img)
x_turn = False
# game engine
while game_end_count <= 9 or not finish:
    for pose in x_pose_list:
        screen.blit(x_image, pose)
    for pose in o_pose_list:
        screen.blit(o_image, pose)
    board_print()
    x_turn = not x_turn
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True
        elif x_turn:
            while True:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == LEFT:
                        x_pose_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                        break
        elif not x_turn:
            while True:
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if event.button == LEFT:
                        o_pose_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                        break
```

[image]

Comment: solved alot time ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the process loops inside the event loops, this loops block the application. An singel event is get by [`event in pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). If this is not called you won't get any new event.

It is completely sufficient to have 1 main loop:

> ```
> while game_end_count <= 9 or not finish:
> ```

and 1 event loop inside the main loop:

> ```
> for event in pygame.event.get():
> ```

Every process loop inside the main loop or even event loop is useless and a bad design.

```py
while game_end_count <= 9 or not finish:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finish = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == LEFT:
                if x_turn:
                    x_pose_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                else:
                    o_pose_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

    for pose in x_pose_list:
        screen.blit(x_image, pose)
    for pose in o_pose_list:
        screen.blit(o_image, pose)
    board_print()

    x_turn = not x_turn
```